# Upgrading service from AngularJS to Angular 5

Tags: angular

This is real world but also academic as I am not a very knowledgeable angular person. I am wanting to upgrade this service but it has several ctor parameters I have not learned how to handle yet.

The old service is like this:

```
class OldSortingSvc implements IOldSorting {

    static $inject = [
        "$q",
        "$log"
    ];

  constructor(
     private readonly $q: ng.IQService,
     private readonly $log: ng.ILogService{
    }
}
```

Normally I would find the new Angular replacement and swap it out in the upgraded service. For example another service might pass $http and in the new service I would use HttpClient.

However in this case I can't find what IQService was replaced with if anything.
Same for ILogService.

So basically looking for the Angular 5 replacements.

Comment: You can upgrade these services an use them in angular. Check the docs to do that: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now created a wrapper for these angularjs services so conversion / migration can move forward while we research and decide on the angular5 replacement.

For example we wrapped LogService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LogService {

   // Use for logging informational messages to the console
   info(infoToLog: any): void {
   console.info(infoToLog);
   }

   // Use for logging warning messages to the console
   warn(infoToLog: any): void {
   console.warn(infoToLog);
   }

  // Use for logging error messages to the console
  error(infoToLog: any): void {
  console.error(infoToLog);
  }

  // Use for logging debug message to the console
  debug(infoToLog: any): void {
  console.debug(infoToLog);
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
class OldSortingSvc implements IOldSorting {

   constructor(
   private logService: LogService) {...}
}
```